# Java Actionlistener changes class variable but Main file doesn't see it if while loop is empty

Tags: java

I created Mbutton class which extends JButton class and inside that i added an Action listener which changes static variable ''mode''

```
public class Mbutton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    public static int mode;
    int own_mode;
    static Color blue1 = new Color(63,93,117);
    static Color blue2 = new Color(46,78,99);
    static Color ground_color = new Color(195,195,195);
    public Mbutton(String name, int o_mode){
        super(name);
        this.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,40));
        this.setForeground(ground_color);
        this.own_mode = o_mode;
        this.setBackground(blue1);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(blue2,5));
        this.addActionListener(this);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == this){
       mode = this.own_mode;
    }
}
```

Inside Main.java class I create three buttons and unless static mode variable inside Mbutton change I don't change screen

```
Mbutton e_but = new Mbutton("Easy",1);
Mbutton n_but = new Mbutton("Normal",2);
Mbutton h_but = new Mbutton("Hard",3);
//some code ...
while (game_mode == 0){
       game_mode = Mbutton.mode;
       System.out.println(Mbutton.mode);
    }
```

Here the problem comes if i add System.out.println() it works fine but otherwise the while loop doesn't see change of mode variable inside Mbutton this is why and how could i fix it or should i fix it?Please be nice i am new in java if you think this question should not exist let me know i can delete it.

[image]

Comment: Odds are you need to declare `mode` and/or `game_mode` as `volatile`, because you access them from multiple threads. *Usually* the better workaround is to avoid accessing shared state from multiple threads and do all of your work on the UI thread, if at all possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an alternative duplicate that has a more detailed explanation of the problem, but I didn't find one. That being said, the duplicate question *does* describe the same kind of problem and the solution should be equally applicable for you.

Comment: I had tried before posting this i had created a Menu2 class which contains mode variable  inside it there were 3 buttons and instead of ActionListener i had added MouseListener but same problem had occured

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you add `volatile`? If so, [edit] your question to include the code you tried (ideally a [mre]).

Comment: Problem is solved  ı added keyword and it worked fine and also i researched keyword in google and it made sense for me thank you so much